# Algorithm suggestions for handling CRUD Soft Deletes for delete and restore with multiple owning models

Tags: sql, orm, crud

I have an active record based ORM with soft deletes (Laravel Eloquent to be specific) in an SQL database.

The 'soft delete' behavior that is built in to the ORM is:
If the record is not deleted, then `deleted_at` is null. When a record is soft deleted, the `deleted_at` field is populated with a timestamp.

The ORM uses the 'deleted_at' field internally in its logic as well as creates the field.  It is difficult to change the type of `deleted_at`.

I have the situation where I have three models (tables), A, B, and C.
Model C belongs to both A and B.  Neither A or B belong to each other.  So table C contains columns to hold foreign keys to A and B.

For C to be valid, both of its parents must not be deleted.  If either A or B is deleted, then C must also be deleted.

However, if A or B is deleted, then restored (i.e. `deleted_at` column set back to null), then C should also be restored.

I'm trying to figure out an algorithm to determine when to restore C, if A and B are restored.

I'm leaning toward a reference counting algorithm?  So when either A or B is deleted, it deletes C and increments C's `deleted_count`.  If A or B is restored, then decrement C `deleted_count` and if `deleted_count` is 0, then restore C?

Does this sound like the best approach for this type of situation?  Any obvious drawbacks?

Comment: Is this SQL, or something else like NoSQL? ORM implies SQL, but it would help to be explicit.

Comment: yes, SQL.  I've added that to the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Avoid reference counting or other workarounds. That requires either manually modifying `C`, or adding triggers. The first option is error-prone, the second harms performance.

Since `C` has foreign keys for `A` and `B`, simply add a "fake" field to `C`'s query: perhaps do this through a view. SQL pseudocode below:

```sql
CREATE VIEW c_view AS
SELECT C.*,
  (CASE WHEN A.deleted_at IS NOT NULL
         AND B.deleted_at IS NOT NULL
        THEN MAX(A.deleted_at, B.deleted_at)
        ELSE NULL
   END) AS deleted_at
FROM C
INNER JOIN A ON A.id = C.A_id
INNER JOIN B ON B.id = C.B_id
```

Just to reiterate, this is *pseduo*-SQL, not something that is guaranteed to be correct syntax or tested. Hopefully it illustrates the overall idea: do not copy data, look it up directly when querying `C`. If you have proper indexes on the primary and foreign keys, it should be lightning-fast and have zero risk of having data recorded incorrectly in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I am working with an off-the-shelf ORM that has the soft delete behavior built-in.  The ORM will try to set the deleted_at field in certain cases, so it may be hard to replace the table with a view.  I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Although I do see what you are saying, I will investigate the possibility of this...  Thanks again